# Optimizing my Search function using foreach() - perfomance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, csla

Here is the deal. I  have got 3 Tables.

1. Main ( contains ID and a list of SubMain ) ~ 130 items  (after first filtering)
2. SubMain (contains SubMainID) ~ 120 items 
   (which got a n to m reference so there is an other table)
3. MainToSub ( contains ID, MainID and SubMainID) ~ 500 items

Main is my Model which im working with and which I display in the GridView. With this `foreach` I search for every Model part which has SearchSubMainID in it. This works but the problem is that i am jumping more then 72000 into the `foreach` which isn't really optimized

```
foreach (var item in MainToSub)
{ 
 // 500 Jumps
    foreach (var temp in Main)
    {
        if (item.MainID == temp.ID && item.SubMainID == SearchSubMainID)
        {
            Model.Add(temp);
            // ~ 10 Jumps
        }
       // 72000 jumps
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to optimize the `foreach`?

Comment: sry my mistake. Main has got ~ 130 items in the worst scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could move one of the checks up one `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in MainToSub)
    if (item.SubMainID == SearchSubMainID)
        foreach (var temp in Main)
            if (item.MainID == temp.ID)
                Model.Add(temp);
```

And this isn't really optimization, but you could also turn it into a LINQ expression:

```
foreach (var temp in MainToSub
    .Where(i => i.SubMainID == SearchSubMainID)
    .Join(Main, i => i.MainID, t => t.ID, (i, t) => t))
        Model.Add(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Dictionary`, make you own class to be used as a key containing the `MainID` and the `SubMainID`. With this `Dictionary` you don't have to search, you just find ... kind of.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `sort` your `lists` and try to search it using `BinarySearch` - you have then O(log n). But solution with `Dictionary` is much simpler.